An error in formula proposed by Riley et al to calculate the sample size
I used the following function to find the minimum sample size for a cox proportional hazard ratio (proposed by Riley et al). Surprisingly, the estimated number of events is more than the expected sample size. I was wondering if you know the reason? Is it due to the high value of event rate? The estimated outcome events is 2131 and estimated sample size is 1715.
 library(pmsampsize)
 pmsampsize(type = "s", csrsquared = 0.051, parameters = 10, rate = 0.6, timepoint = 2, meanfup = 2.07)

* s refers to survival model.
* parameters refers to the number of parameters in model
* rate is event rate
* meanfup is average follow up time (years)
* timepoint refers to timepoint of interest for prediction


       NB: Assuming 0.05 acceptable difference in apparent & adjusted R-squared 
    NB: Assuming 0.05 margin of error in estimation of overall risk at time point = 2  
    NB: Events per Predictor Parameter (EPP) assumes overall event rate = 0.6  
     
                 Samp_size Shrinkage Parameter CS_Rsq Max_Rsq Nag_Rsq   EPP
    Criteria 1        1715     0.900        10  0.051   0.857    0.06 213.0
    Criteria 2         223     0.543        10  0.051   0.857    0.06  27.7
    Criteria 3 *      1715     0.900        10  0.051   0.857    0.06 213.0
    Final SS          1715     0.900        10  0.051   0.857    0.06 213.0
     
     Minimum sample size required for new model development based on user inputs = 1715, 
     corresponding to 3550 person-time** of follow-up, with 2131 outcome events 
     assuming an overall event rate = 0.6 and therefore an EPP = 213       
95% CI for overall risk = (0.683, 0.714), for true value of 0.699 and sample size n = 1715 
     where time is in the units mean follow-up time


@J-J-J, Thanks so much for your time. But my understanding of a survival model is that an event can only happen once per each subject.

Let's say that your time unit is in years. The meanfup is the mean of all observation times: event times for those with the event, right-censoring times for others.
If there's an event rate of 0.6 per time unit, then more than half of the individuals have an event within the first year. In that situation, if the event is terminal (in terms of removal from the study, at least) there's thus no way that you can have a mean follow up as long as 2.07 years as no one lasts that long (on average) without an event. In your example, if you instead specify rate = 1/2.07 (reciprocal of the meanfup value) then you will find a number of events equal to the minimum sample size. Any larger value of rate is inconsistent with a meanfup of 2.07 years, and you get the type of result you show with more events than the minimum sample size.
The function doesn't seem to recognize or flag this problem. I suppose this might allow for multiple events per individual (which is an application of "survival" analysis), but if so this estimate wouldn't take into account the correlations of observations within individuals.
